# Extruding a circle centers on edge instead of center

Tags: extrude

Probably this is something simple that I'm just too blind to see but I think I must have hit a button or something because when I try to extrude into the center it just wants to stick to one edge. I start with a circle and extrude to the center. Everything is fine. I extrude upward. Everything is fine. I try to close the circle. Everything is not fine. Ugh. [image]

Edit: Yes, it was something simple. I just had to change the pivot center.

Comment: please take a minute to read the [tour] and the [help] section to understand how this site works. Don't  add the solution as part of the question, and don't add solved to the title. Write a proper answer in the answers sections instead and mark it as accepted. Other users with the same problem can learn from your experience that way.